# absl::flat_hash_map: efficient way to implement `remove_if`

Tags: c++, algorithm, hashmap, abseil

Is there an efficient way to implement `remove_if` for `absl::flat_hash_map`?

It is my understanding that `absl::flat_hash_map` doesn't return the iterator to the next element, which is generally used for `remove_if`'s implementation.

Does Abseil provide an alternative implementation for such operation?

Pretty much what I want is to iterate on the map and selectively remove items. I'm trying to avoid having a separate container to keep track of what to remove if at all possible.

Comment: "doesn't return the iterator to the next element," ? do you mean ForwardIterators?

Answer (score 4):

`remove_if` reorders elements, and so is inapplicable to associative containers (it has nothing to do with Abseil’s implementation). Just use `std::erase_if` (or `absl::erase_if`).